# Can one recover $G$ from $G/H$?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

I was thinking about a discussion that took place in the comments of some question on this site about quotient groups and isomorphic copies of these.

One of the persons mentioned that in $G/H$ you have more information than in $K$($\simeq G/H$) because in $G/H$ you still have information about $G,H$.

Indeed, you can recover $H$ as the unit of the group $G/H$ and taking the union, one has $G=\bigcup G/H$ .

So set-theoretically, "$(G,H) \to G/H$" is injective (I put quotemarks there because $G/H$ is not only a function of the sets $G,H$ but also of multiplication on $G$).

My question is the following : can you recover the group $G$ knowing the group $G/H$ ? (That is,also recover the multiplication, not only the underlying set)

I guess a precise way to ask the question is : let $C$ be the category of couples $(G,H)$ where $G$ is a group (from here on, this means $G = (E, \cdot)$ where $\cdot$ satisfies the group axioms) and $H$ is a normal subgroup (here $H$ is only the underlying set though) and of group morphisms that preserve the normal subgroup ($f : (G,H) \to (K,N)$ has $f(H)\subset N$) and let $F$ be the functor $C\to \bf{Grp}$ that sends $(G,H)$ to $G/H$ and $f : (G,H) \to (K,N)$ to the canonically associated $\overline{f} : G/H \to K/N$. Is $F$ injective on objects ?

(Though the functorial analysis here isn't necessary, it seemed like a good way of phrasing it)

This says precisely this : given $G/H$ I know $G, H$, but do I know the multiplication ?

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, and in Hagen Von Eitzen's answer, the "trivial case" $G/G$ shows that the question as it now stands is trivial. But a more interesting (I hope) question comes out of it: for which normal subgroups can we recover $G$, or in a more global approach, for what subcategories $D$ of $C$ is the restriction of $F$ to $D$ injective on objects ?

For instance, the (full) subcategory of couples $(G,\{e\})$ has this property (as knowing what $\{a\}\{b\} = a\{e\} b\{e\}$ is in $G/{e}$ tells you what $ab$ is).

Comment: So, can you recover $G$, given $G/G$?

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted. The question was well posed and the OP seems sincere.

Comment: Go OP, your question was legit

Comment: OP: I assume that you would not identify groups that are isomorphic?

Comment: @matboy Language, please.

Comment: Sorry for deleting my previous comment, that was a manipulation mistake. @LordSharktheUnknown : yes indeed, I never think about trivial examples (although I did consider the $H=\{e\}$ case haha). I'll edit the question to broaden it a bit and make it less trivial. Thomas: not in this context, since the issue is in part set-theoretic, as opposed to category-theoretic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the answer that follows resulted from me misinterpreting the question. I understood "recover $G$" to mean recover $G$ up to an isomorphism that preserves the given group structure on $G/H$. But the intention was to recover the group operation on $G$ exactly. Since, whenever $|H|>1$ there is no way of identifying the identity element of $G$, it is only possible to recover $G$ exactly when $|H|=1$.

For any group structure on $H$, is possible that $G = G/H \times H$. So we can only recover $G$ from $G/H$ if there is a unique group structure on $H$, and if the direct product is the only extension.

There is a unique group structure on $H$ if and only if $H$ is finite and has order equal to either $1$ or a prime. If $|H|=1$ then $G$ is determined by $G/H$, so assume that $|G/H|=p$ is prime.

For the extension to be unique, we require first that there is no nontrivial action of $G/H$ on $H$ or equivalently that the commutator quotient $H_1(G/H)$ of $G/H$ is finite and has order coprime to $p-1$. If that holds, then $H \le Z(G)$.

Finally, we require that there is no nonsplit central extension of $H$ by $G/H$, which is equivalent to $H_1(G/H)$ having order coprime to $p$, and the Schur Multiplier $H_2(G/H)$ of $G/H$ being finite and having order coprime to $p$.

Summing up, the conditions for $G$ to be uniquely determined by $G/H$ are that either (i) $|H|=1$; or (ii) $|H|=p$ is finite and prime, $H_1(G/H)$ is finite of order coprime to $p(p-1)$, and $H_2(G/H)$ is finite of order coprime to $p$.

Comment: Why is your first sentence true ?

Comment: Either that is obvious, or I have misunderstood what you mean by "given $G/H$". My understanding is that you are given $Q := G/H$ as a set of sets $Q = \{ H_i : i \in I \}$ for some index set $I$, where each $|H_i|=|H|$, with a group operation defined on $Q$. The only thing you know about the sets $H_i$ is that they all have cardinallty $|H|$. So, for any group $G$ with a normal subgroup $N$ with $|N|=|H|$, and $G/N$ isomorphic to $Q$, it is possible that $G$ is your group.

Comment: Up to isomorphism yes. But $G$ cannot be equal to $G/H \times H$ (assuming the axiom of foundation, which is usually the case) . But re-reading your answer I've noticed one important thing : for each group-structure on $H$, there is a group structure on $G$ so that $G\simeq G/H \times H$. But no matter the cardinality of $H$, as long as it is $>1$, there are many group structures on $H$ (I also wanted to point that out about your answer : you are not "allowed" up-to-isomorphism characterizations here; so even if $|H|=p$ prime, there are mutliple group structures on $H$). (cont)

Comment: (cont) So it would seem that the example I gave in my edit is the only possible one, thanks to your answer I think I can prove it

Comment: I won;t delete my answer, but I will edit it to make it clear that my interpretation of the question was not what you intended. The problem is that it is standard practice to tacitly imply "up to isomorphism" when talking about determining a group.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's what usually done, but here that's not what I wanted. Though your answer provided a way to prove something interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a group of order two with underlying set $\{a,b\}$ (but I won't tell you which of these is the neutral element).
Then $G/G$ is a group with underlying set $\{\{a,b\}\}$ and trivial operation, $\{a,b\}*\{a,b\}=\{a,b\}$.
Clearly, we can recover the underlying set $\{a,b\}$ from this. But all we know about $G/G$ is symmetric with respect to swapping $a\leftrightarrow b$. 
Consequently, with this knowledge alone we cannot determine which of $a,b$ is the neutral element of $G$.

Comment: Yes you are right ! Essentially, this comes down to Lord Shark the Unknown's comment (that a given set $E$ can be given multiple group structures). I edited the question, so that now your answer doesn't fully answer it, sorry. Perhaps you have ideas about my "new" question that you can add to your answer ?

Comment: My answer is not consistent with this one. I was interpreting "recovering $G$" as recovering it up to an isomorphism that induces the given group structure on $G/H$. So according to my interpretation, we know that $G$ is cyclic of order $2$,. so we have recovered $G$.